# R Caret Random Forest view miss-classified

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

Is there a way to get a list of miss-classified items from a random forest model generated in R using caret? The random forest is attempting to classify each item into one of seven possible classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this helps. The names are all generic, but if you provide some example code and data I can clarify things.

```
prediction <- predict(your_rf, testdata, type = "response")
location <- prediction == testdata$target
testdata[location,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the confusion matrix?

```
require(caret)
?confusionMatrix
```

or page 6 of the vignette: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caret.pdf.

Comment: The confusion model prints out nicely using something like `rfmodel$finalModel`, but I would like to look more closely at the incorrectly predicted values, to see if there is more tuning that could be done to capture these values in the model.